# why does my histogram look weird in this stochastic problem plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to write a stochastic program in Python to replicate a fair dice (one dice) roll, such that this one dice is rolled 100 times. I intend to display the output of the dice rolls as a histogram.

I thought histograms had a specific n shape but this is what I have been getting with the code I used below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
for i in range(100):
    num1 = random.choice(range(1,7))
    x.append(num1)
plt.hist(x, bins=6)
plt.xlabel('dice')
plt.show()
```

[myweirdhistogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sgXU.jpg)

Also, is there an easier way to plot a histogram in python when you have, e.g ages as [10,3,5,1] and the frequency in a table as [2,3,4,4]? Do I have to type out the entire frequency of the ages in a list like this: age = [10,10,3,3,3,5,5,5,5,1,1,1,1] before I write the program?
 please see what I mean in the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close()

ages = [88,88,88,88,76,76,76, 65,65,65,65,65,96,96,52,52,52,52,52,98,98,102,102,102,102]

#the frequency was = [4, 3, 5, 2, 5, 2, 4] which corresponded to the ages [88,76,65,96,52,98,102]

num_bins = 25
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(ages, num_bins, facecolor='blue')

plt.xlabel('age')
plt.ylabel('Frequency of occurence')
plt.show()

#my histogram again looks more like a bar chart. Is this because I used bins as the ages?
```

So far, its easier to plot a histogram with random numbers but not a table for me. Here is my second weird output:[mysecondweirdhistogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKAiP.jpg)

Comment: Are you making the lists for the ages and frequencies in another part of your code or are they given to you?

Comment: They are given to me already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> ages = [10,3,5,1]
>>> freqs = [2,3,4,4]
```

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair each age with it's frequency; then use the frequency to add that many to a new container.

```
>>> q = []
>>> for a, f in zip(ages, freqs):
...     q.extend(a for _ in range(f))

>>> q
[10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

`a for _ in range(f)` is a generator expression which will produce `f` `a`'s when iterated. The `extend` method consumes (iterates over) the generator expression. 
 *We* typically use `_` for values that we aren't going to use.

Comment: Yes but I already have the frequencies. I was wondering how to write a simpler code using the already stated frequencies. Imagine if it was a bigger table of frequencies, I wouldn't want to write it out like I did in the code.